# Show that if the eigenvalue of a matrix is 1 and the rows add to 1, then the eigenvectors must be of the form $[c,\ldots, c]^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ such that all entries are positive and the sum of the entries in each row is 1.

Show that $\lambda = -1$ fails to be and eigenvalue and show that the eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1 are of the form $[c,\ldots, c]^T$, where $c$ is nonzero.

I have done the other parts to the problem, but this part is tripping me up. I can understand why this is true, but I cannot prove either part. I tried looking at individual entries of the eigenvector and working with them in the form
$$v_i = a_{i1} v_1 + \ldots + a_{ii} v_i + \ldots + a_{in} v_n
$$
but I got no where. In another attempt I proved as a lemma that $A^T$ had the same eigenvalues, but I didn't end up using this.

Comment: The eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1$ is $v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ \cdot \\ \cdot \\ \cdot \\ 1\\1\\1 \\\end{pmatrix}$. And of course its multiple would be an eigenvector too.

Comment: But also an arbitrary $c$ works: $\lambda c = (a_{i1} + \ldots + a_{in}) c = c$.

Comment: I need to prove that it has to be of this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of your question: You know that $1=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} $ and therefore:

$$ v_i = a_{i1} v_1 + \ldots + \left(1-\sum_{j\neq i,j=1}^n a_{ij}\right) v_i + \ldots + a_{in} v_n. $$

Expanding this and simplifying you get:

$$ a_{i1}(v_1-v_i)+\ldots+a_{in}(v_n-v_i)=0. $$

Where the $a_{ii}$ entry is missing. Now since all $a_{ij}$ are assumed to be positive you get: $v_i=v_j$ for all $i,j$. This shows the claim.

Comment: @Meecolm You actually need to do this for the smallest $v_i\in \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ because else $v_j-v_i$ might be negative and the argument won't work.